# Mutate values when creating a new column by duplicating it

Tags: r, tidyverse

I've a data.frame with over `27000` observations where the column `year` is populated with values between `1975` and `2020` and I do not know how many rows hold each value. I want to create a new column `person` by duplicating `year`. That's pretty easy, but in the new `person` column I need to substitute values in the range 1975-2013 into `NameA` and values in the range 2014-2020 into `NameB`.

Until now, as the range was 1975-2019, I used:

```
text <- text %>%
  mutate(person = year) %>%
  mutate(person = str_replace(person, "201[456789]", "NameB")) %>%
  mutate(person = str_replace(person, "\\d+", "NameA"))
```

but with `2020` into play if I use:

```
text <- text %>%
  mutate(person = year) %>%
  mutate(person = str_replace(person, "20[12][456789]", "NameB")) %>%
  mutate(person = str_replace(person, "\\d+", "NameA"))
```

I get `2010` converted into `NameB`, which is erroneous. I can use

```
text <- text %>%
  mutate(person = year) %>%
  mutate(person = str_replace(person, "201[456789]", "NameB")) %>%
  mutate(person = str_replace(person, "2020", "NameB")) %>%
  mutate(person = str_replace(person, "\\d+", "NameA"))
```

but it does not seen very useful if in the future I have to add `2021`, `2022`, `2023`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would just use an inequality check here:

```r
a_lower <- 1975
a_upper <- 2013
b_lower <- 2014
b_upper <- 2020

text$person <- ifelse(text$year >= a_lower && text$year <= a_upper, "NameA",
                      ifelse(text$year >= b_lower && text$year <= b_upper, "NameB", NA))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint. I have reworked it in a more compact way that avoid the creation of four objects

```
texto <- text %>%
  mutate(person = year) %>%
  mutate(person = ifelse(person %in% as.character(c(1975:2013)),
                      "NameA",
                      "NameB"))
```